# Incorrect exit from while loop when script are run concurrently in different session

Tags: shell-script

I have 2 different scripts: `A1.sh` and `A2.sh`. They are used to start middleware services, for different application. i.e. `A1.sh` will start one app service and `A2.sh` will start other app services. They are running on the same host (AIX).

As the services take some time (around 7 to 15min) to start, I have the below function in both of the scripts. It checks the log and waits until services starts, or times-out after 1000 seconds, if the services don't start in that time period. The scripts work fine if they are run sequentially. However if I run `A1.sh` script in one session and open another session (same host) and run `A2.sh` script, then one of the scripts fails with timeout (though the service starts and is running in background). This timeout is incorrect i.e. it is not 1000 seconds that has passed. Below is the code

```
### wait_for_log
### This wait for a goal message on a specified log, if this is't found the message
### for a timeout period trigger a error message on script log.
###
### usage: wait_for_log [ log_name ] [ start | stop ] [ app_name ] [ timeout ] [ goal_message ]
wait_for_log() {

    FILE_NAME=$1
    ACTION=$2
    APP_NAME=$3
    GOAL_MESSAGE=$5
    GOAL_MESSAGE2=$6
    TIMEOUT=$4

    ELAPSED_TIME=0
    START_TIME=$SECONDS

    alert "info" "${ACTION^^} ${APP_NAME^^}"
    alert "info" "Waiting for ${APP_NAME} ${ACTION}." -n

    tail -0lf $FILE_NAME | while read -t $TIMEOUT LOGLINE
    do
            echo -n "."

            if [ ! -z "$GOAL_MESSAGE2" ]; then
                    if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *$GOAL_MESSAGE2* ]]; then
                            ps -ef | grep "[t]ail " | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill
                            return 2
                    fi
            fi

            if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *$GOAL_MESSAGE* ]]; then
                    ps -ef | grep "[t]ail " | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill
                    return 2
            fi
    done
    EXIT_CODE=$?
    ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))

    if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 2 ];then
            printf "\e[1;32m[OK]\e[0m\n"
            alert "success" "${APP_NAME} took ${ELAPSED_TIME}s to ${ACTION}."
            GLOBAL_ELAPSED_TIME=$((GLOBAL_ELAPSED_TIME + ELAPSED_TIME))
            RETVAL=0
            return 0
    fi

    printf "\e[1;31m[FAIL]\e[0m\n"
    alert "error" "${APP_NAME} ${ACTION} failure, exceed the ${ELAPSED_TIME}s timeout to ${ACTION}."

    RETVAL=1
    exit_script $ACTION
```

}

FILE_NAME is different for 2 scripts. One of the script fails as shown below.

```
<Info>    START RPM
Inside wait for log proc, recieved r2TIMEOUT value: 1000
<Info>    STARTING NODEMANAGER
<Info>    Waiting for NodeManager starting..[FAIL]
<Error>   NodeManager starting failure, exceed the 6s timeout to starting.
<Error>   Ocurred an ERROR when RPM trying to starting.
```

Any idea what is wrong with while loop when running concurrently?

Comment: You probably want your error message to say `exceed the ${TIMEOUT}s` instead of `exceed the ${ELAPSED_TIME}s`..  In any case it is worth checking that TIMOUT is actually set to the value you think it is.

Comment: The EXIT_CODE won't be 2, as the `return 2` means that the function is terminated at that point.

Comment: `$SECONDS` is a number between 0…59, because it's the seconds of the current time. So `START_TIME` also has the same range, and your `ELAPSED_TIME` will normally never be something related to the `$TIMEOUT` you set.

Comment: `! -z` should be `-n` to check if string is nonzero

Comment: Thanks, I will check the ps command. However what i observe is that the script breaks out too early before the actual GOAL_MESSAGE is matched and that is when the ps command should be running to kill the tail command. The value of EXIT_CODE when it breaks it of loop is 0 and not 2. Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grep'ing of the `ps` output for 'tail' will be the cause, I think. Try to grep for `$FILE_NAME`, so that you do not accidentally kill the other scripts tail process, but instead kill the one for your correct loop.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, It is infact the ps command for tail having the issue. After fixing the ps command for tail to grep for FILE_NAME as well the issue seems to be fixed, i.e. both the scripts are running to completion without breaking out of the loop.